# Member of different class instances referring to the same object via argument default value in method definition

Tags: python, class, static, multiple-instances, keyword-argument

The Python documentation says about keyword arguments (glossary):

> ...The variable name designates the local name in the function to which the value is assigned...

Thus I thought different instances of a class are truly different unless stated
explicitly. Yet the following code refers one member variable of both instances
of the class to the /same/ object, apparently via the given default value (as if the
keyword dictionary of the method was a class variable ("static")). Once one modifies the
member everything's fine, but if for some reason that doesn't happen:

1. I wonder if there is a good reason for the code to behave like it does,
   because it's not what I would expect at all (see markings in code and output) and
2. Whether there is a good solution to the problem (apart from using 'copy').
   Thanks.

   ```
   class C:
       def setParams(self):
           self.e = []
       def setParamsKw(self, kw=['default list']): # <----- kw arg.
           self.eKw = kw                           # <--- that member should
                                                   #      default to the
                                                   #      default argument
                                                   #      (use 'kw.copy()'?)

   def outputMember():
       print " c1.e=", c1.e
       print " c2.e=", c2.e
       print " type(c1.e)=", type(c1.e)
       print " type(c2.e)=", type(c2.e)
       print " c1.e == c2.e:", c1.e == c2.e
       print " c1.e is c2.e:", c1.e is c2.e

   def outputMemberKw():
       print " c1.eKw=", c1.eKw
       print " c2.eKw=", c2.eKw
       print " type(c1.eKw)=", type(c1.eKw)
       print " type(c2.eKw)=", type(c2.eKw)
       print " c1.eKw == c2.eKw:", c1.eKw == c2.eKw
       print " c1.eKw is c2.eKw:", c1.eKw is c2.eKw # <----- this result
                                                    #      is unexpected


   c1 = C()
   c2 = C()

   print " c1 == c2:",  c1 == c2
   print " c1 is c2:",  c1 is c2

   print "Calling setParams for both instances:"
   c1.setParams()
   c2.setParams()
   outputMember()

   print "Calling setParamsKw for both instances:"
   c1.setParamsKw()
   c2.setParamsKw()
   outputMemberKw()

   print "Now manually modifying members of c1:"
   c1.e = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
   c1.eKw = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
   print "e:"
   outputMember()
   print "eKw:"
   outputMemberKw()
   ```

Output:

```
c1 == c2: False
 c1 is c2: False
Calling setParams for both instances:
 c1.e= []
 c2.e= []
 type(c1.e)= <type 'list'>
 type(c2.e)= <type 'list'>
 c1.e == c2.e: True
 c1.e is c2.e: False
Calling setParamsKw for both instances:
 c1.eKw= ['default list']
 c2.eKw= ['default list']
 type(c1.eKw)= <type 'list'>
 type(c2.eKw)= <type 'list'>
 c1.eKw == c2.eKw: True
 c1.eKw is c2.eKw: True
Now manually modifying members of c1:
e:
 c1.e= [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
 c2.e= []
 type(c1.e)= <type 'list'>
 type(c2.e)= <type 'list'>
 c1.e == c2.e: False
 c1.e is c2.e: False
eKw:
 c1.eKw= [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
 c2.eKw= ['default list']
 type(c1.eKw)= <type 'list'>
 type(c2.eKw)= <type 'list'>
 c1.eKw == c2.eKw: False
 c1.eKw is c2.eKw: False
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def setParamsKw(self, kw=None): # <----- kw arg.
            self.eKw = kw  if kw == None else ['default list']
```

should work

Comment: This will set `kw` to `['default list']` if you pass in an empty list.